# How should I structure a navigation bar?

Tags: html

I want to create a navigation bar like this:

[image: navigation bar]

How would I structure such a thing? Obviously there should be one external div with a blue background. But what about the child elements? How should they be structured? Thanks.

Comment: You could use any of them. I'm afraid the question you ask is too broad.

Comment: @Blunderfest I don't think this is a broad question. He/she wants to know what is the best practice

Comment: Best practice for layout of two elements next to each other? Short answer, you can use any of them, longer answer would involve that even with using any of them there are many ways of achieving the look being asked for, and they depend on a myriad of factors. I suppose it's my opinion that this would be too opinion based :).

Comment: Yes I want to know what should follow? @Blunderfest

Comment: Yes I want to know same @mparnisari Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no generalized answer on how to structure a page properly. There are general standards for using technologies, but over all getting your page to present properly is more important then how many or which type of elements you use.

For example if you want your page to auto re-size then you might want to use Divs or Tables. If you want your text to wrap without crossing the entire page, you might want to use a table, or spans...

I can show you some references to floating for CSS... But even in this type of example you could create divs within divs, that are styles appropriately to "taste"; or you could use spans within spans.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

The major caveat to this explination is that corporate environments will normally have a style guide generated by advertising or marketing that will dictate how the eccomerse or client present sites, and data is represented. This will normally force you to use as an ex: Divs vs Spans.

Comment: Please give me more detail.@Dethryl

Comment: Sorry, I am at work and don't have tons of spare time to build up a working code example... But what I can show you is this: http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_layout_float   In this example of floating... The page can be resized without objects "bumping" into one another, so you can get a customized viewing experience on a mobile device, as well as a full page experience on a PC web browser, using the same page. Try making the window smaller and you will see the text and image adjust accordingly.

Comment: The effect mentioned in the comment above can be achieved using Divs, Spans, Tables, Frames, and a plethora of other HTML objects. My personal favorite is Divs, but like I was hinting at in my original answer there is no "1 right way" to do this. And doing it one way versus another might come down to the difference being as simple as how many characters you have to type...

Comment: Also found a pretty nice blog post that goes into great detail about how to layout and manage elements in CSS -> https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Comment: Also found another good post about absolute positioning instead of floating, if you wanted to be specific about where elements actually appear on your pages... http://alistapart.com/article/fauxabsolutepositioning

Answer (score -1):

To create a navigation bar, you'll need something like so

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  padding: 30px 40px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 49%;
  text-align: right;
}

li.title {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="title">Welcome to Our World</li>
    <li>We Work Best</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

This would generally be considered the most common way to structure a nav bar.

Answer (score -1):

Each element has a different default display property so I think in this case it depends of the element.
The display property of the span is Inline

– The inline elements line up horizontally as like

Inline Inline Inline

The display property of the div is block

https://iamarunkumar.wordpress.com/2010/02/10/what-is-the-default-display-property-for-span-and-div/